# Can't access port 8000 on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, django-deployment

I have an EC2 instance which only has private IP (I cant create public as we have restrictions in our org). I have deployed django application on that EC2 instance on port 8000.

Can anyone suggest what are the ways I have to access that app? Even the Elastic IP is not possible because VPC does not have an Internet Gateway. Is there a way like accessing app in EC2 through API Gateway or something similar?

Comment: What sort of access do you want? Is it just for you, or for anyone on the Internet to access? Do you have a VPN connection to the VPC containing the EC2 instance, or perhaps your company has a network connection to it via Direct Connect? How do you normally access the instance (eg to configure software on it)?

Comment: I want vpn secured access for my django app. Yes our company has vpn and i am trying to access that app from vpn iself. I am able to ssh into that ec2 instance. But not able to access the app from browser. i think its problem of port settings. How can i configure ec2 request to port 8000?

Comment: What are the settings of the Security Group(s) associated with the instance? Does it have an Inbound rule permitting access on port 8000?

Comment: Inbound Rules has permission for port 80.And I am not allowed to add permission for other ports.

Comment: In that case, you need something running on that instance (eg a proxy) that accepts traffic on Port 80 and sends it to port 8000. Alternatively, change the app to listen on Port 80.

Comment: Yup. I tried that, but Its throwing permission denied for that too. So we now decided to skip that part for now and use api-gateway + lambda   combination to build the apis. We will move to this once we get admin access to our VPC. Thank you for your help!